# Why does the period of $X_n = \cos(\omega_0 n + \phi)$ decrease as $\omega_0$ increases to $\pi$, but increase as $\omega_0$ increases to $2\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

In *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, Oppenheim writes

> For the discrete-time sinusoidal signal $x[n]=A \cos(\omega_0 n + \phi)$, as $\omega_0$ increases from $\omega_0 = 0$ toward $\omega_0 = \pi$, $x[n]$ oscillates progressively more rapidly. However, as $\omega_0$ increases from $\omega_0 = \pi$ to $\omega_0 = 2\pi$ , the oscillations become slower.

Suppose I have the discrete-time signal $$X_n = A\cos(\omega_0 n + \phi).$$

If $N$ is its fundamental period, we have that $\omega_0 N = 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$, and so $k$ must be the smallest integer for which $\frac{2 \pi}{\omega_0}$ is itself an integer. If I let $\omega_0 = r \pi$, where $0 < r < 2$ is rational, how can I show that the period decreases as $r \to 1$? To simplify, I can let $r = 1 - 1/m$, and we have that
$$N = \frac{2\pi}{r\pi}k = \frac{2m}{m - 1}k = \left(1 + \frac{m+1}{m-1}\right)k$$
which I believe implies that $k = \frac{m-1}{\text{gcd}(m-1,m+1)}$. I would need to show that this decreases in $m$.

Is there a good geometric picture for why the above fact is true?

Comment: Use $cos(\omega_0n)=cos((2\pi-\omega_0)n)$.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66573/increasing-parameter-omega-in-xn-ej-omega-n

Comment: For a good geometric picture: the DFT "lives" on the unit circle, $z = e^{j\omega}$ of the z plane.  DC is at $z=e^{j0}=1$.  Positive frequencies are on the upper half of the unit circle, $\omega \in (0, \pi]$.  Negative frequencies are on the lower half of the unit circle, $\omega \in [-\pi,0)$.  When going around the unit circle in a CCW direction, if you cross the boundary $\omega = \pi$, you have wrapped around from the high positive frequencies to an alias of the high negative frequencies.

Comment: This is explained in [this answer over at dsp.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/17728/4298).